# PHP echo at an earlier line of the script

Tags: php, echo

I have a PHP script that generates html. In the bottom part of the script I do some computations using PHP. I want to echo the result in the top part. Is this possible.

```
//script begins
<?php
....
//I want to echo the result here
....
....
....
//PHP computations, result in $result
//I do now want to echo result here but in the top part of the output document.
?>
//script ends
```

More Information- The output is an html document. I do some computations in the body part for which there is no workaround. I want to echo the output in the head part.

Comment: You can't do that, you need to calculate the values before you output them. You could cheat by using JavaScript to move the contents after the page loads. There shouldn't be any reason why you can't rework your code to do all the computations before you output the HTML though.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I will try wrapping the computation and entire body part in a function, print the result and call the function. Will that be a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the computation where you need it. like this

```php
<?php
// computations here and store the values in variables
$value = 'xyz';

// or define a function here that you can use
function func ()
{ return false; }

//html here, some exmaples
?>
<div><?php echo $value;?></div>
<h1><?php echo func();?></h1>

?>
```